# How to prove this identity involving Lerch function?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, special-functions

Trying to find another way to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148849/finding-int-pi-2-pi-2-frac-log-1-b-sin-x-sin-x-mathrm-dx/4354026#4354026), I arrived at a point where I cannot simplify anymore.

The solution being
$$I_1=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\csc (x) \log \left(\frac{1+b \sin (x)}{1-b \sin (x)}\right)=\pi  \sin ^{-1}(b)$$

I am stuck with
$$I_2=\frac 12\Bigg[a_+ \Phi
   \left(a_+^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)+a_- \Phi
   \left(a_-^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)\Bigg]\quad \text{where}\quad a_\pm=b\pm\sqrt{b^2-1}$$ $\Phi(.)$ being the Lerch transcendent function.

**How to prove that, for $\color{red}{-1 \le b \le 1}$, $\color{red}{I_2=I_1}$ ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As $-1\le b\le 1$, we define
\begin{equation}
 b=\cos\beta
\end{equation}
with $0\le\beta\le\pi$. Then
\begin{align}
 a_{\pm}&=b\pm\sqrt{b^2-1}\\
 &=e^{\pm i\beta}
\end{align}
From the definition of the Lerch transcendent function,
\begin{equation}
\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{\left[(a+k)^2\right]^{s/2}} 
\end{equation}
for $|z|<1 \bigvee \left(|z|=1\bigwedge \Re s>1\right)\bigwedge -a\notin \mathbb{N}$,
we have
\begin{align}
 I_2&=\frac 12\left[a_+ \Phi
   \left(a_+^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)+a_- \Phi
   \left(a_-^2,2,\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\\
   &=\frac12\left[e^{i\beta}\Phi\left(e^{2i\beta},2,\frac12\right)+e^{-i\beta}\Phi\left(e^{-2i\beta},2,\frac12\right)\right]\\
   &=4\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos\left((2k+1)\beta\right)}{(2k+1)^2}
\end{align}
Using the classical Fourier series,
\begin{equation}
 |\beta|=\frac\pi2-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos\left((2k+1)\beta\right)}{(2k+1)^2}
\end{equation}
we deduce
\begin{align}
 I_2&=\pi\left( \frac\pi2-\beta \right)\\
 &=\pi\sin^{-1}(b)
\end{align}
as expected.

Comment: Hi Paul ! Nice way to do it. I did not think about Fourier series (which I did not use a single time in the last sixty years or more). $\to +1$ for sure (at least for the time being). Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Claude! In 2022, Fourier series are back! :-) Cheers.

Comment: Paul : just out of  curiosity, what is $I_2$ for $|b|>1$. Its real part is $\frac{\pi ^2}{2}$ (OK with that) but what about the imaginary part ?

Comment: One can express the Lerch function in terms of polylog [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.06.03.0031.01)
$$\Phi(z,2,1/2)=\frac2{\sqrt z}\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(\sqrt z)-\operatorname{Li}_2(\sqrt z)\right]$$
and with the [identity](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.07.17.0003.01) 
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(z)+\operatorname{Li}_2(\frac1z)=-\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac12\log^2(-z)$$
as $a_+a_-=1$, we obtain
$$I_2=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-i\pi\log (a_+)$$ which seems numerically correct.